# How to insert into and Insert select together with sql

Tags: php, mysql

Somebody help me. i can't  `insert` into and `Insert select` together with sql

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
if($lati==$row["lat_1"] && $lngi==$row["longti_1"]) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO form_content (id,date_db,detail_1,detail_2,detail_3,detail_4,detail_5,detail_6,detail_7str,detail_8str,detail_9str,service) INSERT INTO form_content (id,service) SELECT id,service FROM locate_test VALUES ('', '".$_POST['date_db']."','".$_POST['no_1']."', '".$_POST['no_2']."', '".$_POST['no_3']."', '".$_POST['no_4']."', '".$_POST['no_5']."', '".$_POST['no_6']."', '$chk','".$_POST['no_8']."','".$_POST['no_9']."')"; 

         if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
               echo "<script>";
               echo "alert('New record created successfully');";
               echo "window.location.href='Chartjs.php';";
               echo "</script>";
         } else {
               echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
         }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would assume your SQL is incorrect, you are doing two INSERTs one after another.

Comment: Prepare your queries and bind your parameters, don't pass it directly.

Comment: how to insert into select together $_POST ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your string insert values into database what you want :

```
"INSERT INTO form_content (id,date_db,detail_1,detail_2,detail_3,detail_4,detail_5,detail_6,detail_7str,detail_8str,detail_9str,service) 
VALUES ('', '".$_POST['date_db']."','".$_POST['no_1']."', '".$_POST['no_2']."', '".$_POST['no_3']."', '".$_POST['no_4']."', '".$_POST['no_5']."', '".$_POST['no_6']."', '$chk','".$_POST['no_8']."','".$_POST['no_9']."', 'service here')";
```

Comment: i mean insert into select  Example : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp but i have $_POST i need to insert into select  together with $_POST

Comment: Oh, probably it is this :   "INSERT INTO form_content (id,date_db,detail_1,detail_2,detail_3,detail_4,detail_5,detail_6,detail_7str,detail_8str,detail_9str,service) 
SELECT  id, '".$_POST['date_db']."','".$_POST['no_1']."', '".$_POST['no_2']."', '".$_POST['no_3']."', '".$_POST['no_4']."', '".$_POST['no_5']."', '".$_POST['no_6']."', '$chk','".$_POST['no_8']."','".$_POST['no_9']."', service
FROM locate_test"

Comment: can't insert  Show ERROR: Could not able to execute

Comment: You should print insert string and test with SLQ management tool to detect issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
define( 'DB_HOST', "*******" );
define( 'DB_NAME', "*******" );
define( 'DB_USER', "*******" );
define( 'DB_PASS', "*******" );


$mConnection = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

// Get id and service for insert 
$queryOne = mysqli_query( $mConnection, "SELECT id, service FROM locate_test" ); // you need add WHERE `filed` = 'anything';
$mRow     = mysqli_fetch_row( $queryOne );
$mId      = $mRow[0];
$mService = $mRow[1];

$queryTwo = "INSERT INTO form_content (id, date_db, detail_1, detail_2, detail_3, detail_4, detail_5, detail_6, detail_7str, detail_8str, detail_9str, service) VALUES ('$mId', '{$_POST['date_db']}','{$_POST['no_1']}', '{$_POST['no_2']}', '{$_POST['no_3']}', '{$_POST['no_4']}', '{$_POST['no_5']}', '{$_POST['no_6']}', '{$chk}','{$_POST['no_8']}','{$_POST['no_9']}', '$mService')";
mysqli_query( $mConnection, $queryTwo );
```

I think there's No Way to use your code, please check out this.

**NOTE:** for *queryOne* you must add a WHERE to find your row.

I hope it helps.

Comment: @GuelWu Sorry I forget to change actionOne to queryOne